# vector decomposition using eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

The eigenvalues of  the matrix 
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 3 & 0 \\
        3 & 0 & 4 \\
        0 & 4 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
are $5$, $0$, and $‐5$.

**Question:**  Decompose the vector $(50, 0, 0)^T$ as a linear combination of eigenvectors.

Comment: from professor. I don't what does it mean? I found material abot matrix decomposition but I couldn't see anything about vector.

Comment: Have you computed the eigenvectors corresponding to your eigenvalues? That would be the first step.

Comment: yes I have eigenvectors : 

for  -5 = [1; -5/3; 4/3]  , for 5 = [1; 5/3 ; 4/3] and for 0 = [1;0;-3/4]

Comment: So now you have a simple linear equation system....

Comment: So the question you are now being asked is to find scalars $a, b$ and $c$ such that

$$av_{1} + bv_{2} + cv_{3} = (50, 0, 0)^{T}$$

where the $v_{i}$ are the eigenvectors you have found.

Comment: Can you please expand you commend addy2012. Im not good at linear algebra.

Comment: Thank you Mattos. can you add your commend as an  answer.

Comment: Huh? You know how to find eigenvectors but don't know what a linear equation system is?

Comment: : ) actually I don't know decomposition?  If I know av1+bv2+cv3= V , I can understand you. thank you addy2012 for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, determine the eigenvectors $u_i$ for each eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ ($i \in \{1, 2, 3\}$).

Then, solve the linear equation system:

$$\begin{pmatrix}  -- u_1 -- \\ -- u_2 --  \\ -- u_3 -- \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}  \alpha \\ \beta \\ \gamma \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}  50\\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} 
$$

For $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}$

Then your decomposition is:

$$\alpha u_1 + \beta u_2 + \gamma u_3 = (50, 0, 0)^T$$